# Cannot run tflearn with sklearn's GridSearchCV

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, cross-validation, grid-search, tflearn

I intend to perform a grid search over hyperparams of a tflearn model. It seems that the model produced by `tflearn.DNN` is not compatible with sklearn's GridSearchCV expectations:

```
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
import tflearn
import tflearn.datasets.mnist as mnist
import numpy as np

X, Y, testX, testY = mnist.load_data(one_hot=True)

encoder = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 784])
encoder = tflearn.fully_connected(encoder, 256)
encoder = tflearn.fully_connected(encoder, 64)

# Building the decoder
decoder = tflearn.fully_connected(encoder, 256)
decoder = tflearn.fully_connected(decoder, 784)

# Regression, with mean square error
net = tflearn.regression(decoder, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=0.01,
                         loss='mean_square', metric=None)

model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_verbose=0)

grid_hyperparams = {'optimizer': ['adam', 'sgd', 'rmsprop'], 'learning_rate': np.logspace(-4, -1, 4)}
grid = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid=grid_hyperparams, scoring='mean_squared_error', cv=2)
grid.fit(X, X)
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-fd63245cd0a3> in <module>()
     22 grid_hyperparams = {'optimizer': ['adam', 'sgd', 'rmsprop'], 'learning_rate': np.logspace(-4, -1, 4)}
     23 grid = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid=grid_hyperparams, scoring='mean_squared_error', cv=2)
---> 24 grid.fit(X, X)
     25 
     26 

/home/deeplearning/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/grid_search.py in fit(self, X, y)
    802 
    803         """
--> 804         return self._fit(X, y, ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
    805 
    806 

/home/deeplearning/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/grid_search.py in _fit(self, X, y, parameter_iterable)
    539                                          n_candidates * len(cv)))
    540 
--> 541         base_estimator = clone(self.estimator)
    542 
    543         pre_dispatch = self.pre_dispatch

/home/deeplearning/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in clone(estimator, safe)
     45                             "it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator "
     46                             "as it does not implement a 'get_params' methods."
---> 47                             % (repr(estimator), type(estimator)))
     48     klass = estimator.__class__
     49     new_object_params = estimator.get_params(deep=False)

TypeError: Cannot clone object '<tflearn.models.dnn.DNN object at 0x7fead09948d0>' (type <class 'tflearn.models.dnn.DNN'>): it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator as it does not implement a 'get_params' methods.
```

Any idea how I could get an object suitable for GridSearchCV?

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with tflearn, but I do have some basic background in Python and sklearn. Judging from the error in your StackOverflow screenshot, tflearn **models **do not have the same methods or attributes as scikit-learn estimators. This is understandable as they are not, well, scikit-learn estimators.

Sklearn’s grid search CV only works on objects that have the same methods and attributes as scikit-learn estimators (e.g. has fit() and predict() methods). If you are intent on using sklearn’s grid search, you will have to write your own wrapper around the tflearn model to make it work as a drop in replacement for an sklearn estimator, meaning you’ll have to write your own class that has the same methods as any other scikit-learn estimator, but uses the tflearn library to actually implement these methods.

To do that, understand the code for a basic scikit-learn estimator (preferably one you know well) and see what the methods fit(), predict(), get_params(), etc. actually do to the object and its internals. Then write your own class using the tflearn library.

To get started, a quick Google search reveals that this repository is “a thin scikit-learn style wrapper for tensorflow framework”: DSLituiev/tflearn (https://github.com/DSLituiev/tflearn). I have no idea if this will work as a drop in replacement for Grid Search, but it’s worth a look.